# Android Gradle conflict

Tags: android, facebook, gradle, gradle-dependencies

I am trying to include the Facebook api into my android project. Everything was working fine before adding the Facebook sdk dependency to the gradle. I tried many solutions but they don't work. After adding the dependency the collapsibleToolbar layout cannot be inflated it gives a inflateException.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
```

On reading different solutions I noticed that there is some problem in the dependency hence I have generated the gradle dependency graph as follows

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapplication.sample"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    renderscriptTargetApi 23
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
//Picasso
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
//Volley
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile project(path: ':volley')
//twitter
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
//facebook
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'){
    exclude module: 'support:appcompat-v7'
}



}
```

Following is the dependency graph :

```
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 -> 25.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.0.0
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.0.0 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.0.0 (*)
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+ -> 25.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0
+--- com.android.support:design:23.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0 -> 25.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 -> 25.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 -> 25.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 -> 25.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+ -> 23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
+--- com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0
+--- project :volley
+--- com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.1
|    +--- com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:2.3.1
|    |    +--- com.twitter:twitter-text:1.13.0
|    |    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.14
|    |    +--- com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:2.3.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1
|    |    |    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2
|    |    |    |    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2
|    |    |    |    |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0
|    |    |    |    |         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1
|    |    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.14
|    |    |    \--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
|    +--- com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:2.3.1
|    |    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.14
|    |    +--- com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:2.3.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 -> 25.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
|    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.14
|    \--- com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:2.3.0 (*)
\--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5) -> 4.19.0
     +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0 (*)
     +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0 (*)
     +--- com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.0
     |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0
     \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0
          +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
          \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0
               \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
```

I have tried to exclude support:v4 and support:appcompat-v7 from the facebook sdk. How do I solve this problem??

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade your project to android api 25? (compileSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion etc)

Comment: @MaximOstrovidov  Yes, that solved the problem.. thanks a lot